# How to store the predicted classnames from darknet YOLO?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition, darknet

I am new to using the YOLOv2 for a real-time object detection application for a project.

I followed the steps from the [darknet](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) website. And for the real-time detection using a webcam, I ran this command (below):

`./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/tiny-yolo.cfg tiny-yolo.weights`

This opens up a new camera window which detects any objects in the view and also prints out the predicted classes in the terminal. I am trying to find out a way to store these classes so I can use it for a different purpose.

Could anyone suggest me the filename within the darknet directory which is printing out the classnames in the terminal?

Comment: Hello, i have add info on how to store detections, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, the file you are looking for is **voc.names**, in the **/data** folder.

It contains the words thrown when a detection happen.

If you want to translate detections in your language, this is the file to modify.

For your other question, how to store detection, in linux it can be done directly by piping the stdout.

Detections will be writen line by line into a file detected.txt:

```
./darknet detector demo cfg/coco.data cfg/tiny-yolo.cfg tiny-yolo.weights >> detected.txt
```

I am working currently on this on my spare time.

I am using detections then speak them with audio files *in french*. The detection are doubled to detect left and right of the screen. 
It works with the webcam, the desktop, or a wifi camera.
I have also made an installer script, to easily deploy yolo from scratch.

Maybe you will find interesting stuffs, if so please star! I am thinking to add other languages.

https://github.com/webdev23/aten

> Helper scripts to quickly install YOLO darknet image recognition
>   neural network into a linux shell.
>
> It can take snapshots of the desktop screen, the system webcam, or
>   from an Ambarella wifi streaming live camera.
>
> This will detect objects into snapshots and speak them with espeak.
>
> As it use NO GPU, it can run pretty anywhere.
>
> The snapshots and recognition process takes around 1-2 seconds,
>   depending the running machine.
>
> Dev goal: Automotive usage.
>
> Usage: ./scan [[url|screen|webcam|cam] [en|fr]
>
> Default: webcam
>
> Racing install: Run the script from a blank folder!
>
> ./install
>
> Or directly:
>
> php <(curl https://webdev23.github.io/aten/install)

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your reply.  I tried running the command you suggested,( piping the stdout into a file), but the predicted class don't get printed into the file. It just says "Demo".. and that's all.  Do you have any more advice on this?

Comment: And, have you ever any luck trying to run the darknet.py file? I know the darknet YOLO detector is written in C, but I wanted to find out whether I can run the program in python?